# Find Acceleration Of A Buoyancy Force Of A Balloon In U.S. Customary Units (1-49E)

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, statics

The problem in my text (Thermodynamics An Engineering Approach, Cengel & Boles, 2nd Ed.) is stated as follows:

Balloons are often filled with helium gas because it weighs only about one-seventh of what air weighs under identical conditions. The buoyancy force, which can be expressed as $F_b=\rho_{air} g V_{balloon}$, will push the balloon upward. If the balloon has a diameter of $30ft$ and carries two people, $140 lb_m$ each, determine the acceleration of the balloon when it is first released. Assume the density of air is $\rho_{air}=0.0724 \frac{lb_m}{ft^3}$, and neglect the weight of the ropes and the cage.

Answer: $45.1 \frac{ft}{s^2}$

I can easily find a solution in S.I. units. It is the U.S. Customary units that I am having difficulty with.

Given:
$$
r = 15ft \\
m_{people} = 2 \cdot 140 lb_m \\
\rho_{air}=0.0724 \frac{lb_m}{ft^3} \\
$$
Let us begin by finding $V$ and $F_b$:
$$
V_{balloon} = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 =  \frac{4}{3}\pi (15ft)^3 = 14137 ft^3 \\
F_b=\rho_{air} g V_{balloon} = \frac{0.0724\frac{lb_m}{ft^3}}{32.174\frac{lb_m}{lb_f}\frac{ft}{s^2}}\cdot32.174\frac{ft}{s^2} \cdot 14137 ft^3 = 1023 lb_f\\
$$
Next let us find all masses:
$$
m_{people} = 2 \cdot 140lb_m = 280 lb_m = \frac{280lb_m}{32.174\frac{ft}{s^2}} = 8.703slugs \\ (Q1: \: how\: do\: I\: make\: the\: units\: work\: out?) \\
m_{He} = \frac{\rho_{air} V_{balloon}}{7} = \frac{0.0724\frac{lb_m}{ft^3}}{7 \cdot 32.174\frac{lb_m}{lb_f}\frac{ft}{s^2}} \cdot 14137 ft^3 = 4.545 slugs \\
(Q2: \: how\: do\: I\: make\: the\: units\: work\: out?) \\
m_{total} = m_{people} + m_{He} = (8.703 + 4.545) slugs = 13.25 slugs$$

Now let us determine the $F_{net}$ and finally the acceleration by Newton's Second Law:
$$
F_{total} = m_{total}g = 13.25 slugs \cdot 32.174\frac{ft}{s^2} = 426lb_f\\
(Q3: \: how\: do\: I\: make\: the\: units\: work\: out?) \\
F_{net} = F_b - F_{total} = (1023-426) lb_f = 596.7 lb_f \\
a = \frac{F_{net}}{m_{total}} = \frac{596.7 lb_f}{13.25 slugs} = 45.1 \frac{ft}{s^2} \\
(Q4: \: how\: do\: I\: make\: the\: units\: work\: out?) \\
$$
I was able to duplicate the solution but I had to fudge on the units because I am not sure how to convert between $lb_f$ to $lb_m$ to $slugs$. Please advise by using the very same calculations in this problem. Please select any of Q1 to Q4 to demonstrate how to use unit conversion factors in U.S. customary units.

Comment: Let me [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(mass)) that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps, convert the input values to whatever units you are comfortable with, then convert the answer to whatever units the question is asking for.  If the question doesn't specify units for the answer, and this isn't implied from discussions in class, then answer in any reasonable units you like.

I said *reasonable* units, since deliberately tweaking the professor's or TA's nose is not a good idea.  He might be fine with meters/second instead of feet/second or miles/hour, but furlongs/fortnight is just deliberate provocation.

In any case, pounds-force, pounds-mass, and slugs are all very common units that are well defined out there, so answering that part of your question is pointless.  Go look them up.  Whether you like them or not, they are units you should at least know how to use, perhaps just looking up the conversion constants when you need them.

Comment: If you are good with units please help me by showing how any of the calculations seen in the problem might correctly be done with appropriate unit conversion factors. For example how do we go from lbm to slugs and back to lbf in any of the calculations above.

Comment: @Jules: That's *really basic* stuff.  Clearly you haven't even tried to look it up.

Comment: Yes I did look it up at several places. The problem is that no one uses real world like examples to show how to use them. I guess I am not as smart as most engineering students.